# Getting id of the form in formset which is being edited

Tags: python, django

I have a Django template that renders a table comprising Django formsets.

Template (*simplified*)

```
<table id = 'my_table'>
   {% for form in my_formset %}
       <tr><td>{{form.my_field}}</td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now, I have a Jquery code which looks something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#my_table tr input[type = text], input[type = number]', function(){
        // currently the following code handles save event
        // $.post ('/save_my_form/', $form.serialize()) 
    });
```

And the corresponding Django view

```
def save_my_form(request):
    # .......
    for form in order_draft_formset:
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
    # .......
```

The problem with this approach is that I modify only one single input element in one single form, whereas the Django view loops through entire formset. The question is, is there any built-in Django way to fetch the form within which the modified input is localized, so that I save only this exact form in my view without going through the entire formset. I feel that Jquery must somehow submit some info via post-request parameters that would help Django do that. As for now, I am thinking of parsing the automatically Django-generated id, f.e, id_form-5-my_field, and getting "5" out of it in Jquery and passing this "5" to Django. But I have a terrible feeling that this is a "dirty" method, and there must be a cleaner way to do that. Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if form.has_changed():
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Comment: Yep, practical and elementary. Didn't think about it. Thank you )